# How do javascript desktop apps work?

Tags: javascript, html

looking at applications like Adobe's Brackets, how did they manage to make the javascript / html stack behave like a desktop app? In other words, what's the underlying magic that makes it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there are a few options really:

- There's [HTML Applications](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_Application), but they're pretty much dead and gone.
- There are [Chrome Apps](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/first_app.html) too
- Special frameworks (such as [TideSDK](http://www.tidesdk.org/)) also exist, which act in a similar manner to PhoneGap

Answer (score 1):

In addition to BenM's list, there is also the [Adobe AIR](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/) technology:

> Adobe AIR is a cross-platform runtime that enables you to use your
>   existing Flash/ActionScript or HTML/JavaScript development skills and
>   tools to build and deploy applications, games, and videos outside the
>   browser and on mobile devices.

I only can make a guess how they work, but I think that some "mini-browser-engines" are embedded within a windows frame and glued together.